# Нарисовать нижнюю границу TextBox в WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть метод, который создает текстовые поля с заданными параметрами

```
private void SetTextBox(int positionX, int positionY, string txtText)
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();            

    txt.Location = new Point(positionX, positionY);
    txt.Size = new Size(200, 15);
    txt.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    txt.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(176, 178, 183);
    txt.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 240);

    FontFamily fontFamaly = new FontFamily(System.Drawing.Text.GenericFontFamilies.SansSerif);
    txt.Font = new Font("Verdana", 16.5f, FontStyle.Italic);

    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(57,54,56));
    txt.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(pen, Convert.ToSingle(positionX), Convert.ToSingle(positionY + txt.Size.Height), Convert.ToSingle(positionX + txt.Size.Width), Convert.ToSingle(positionY + txt.Size.Height));


    txt.Text = txtText;
    Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

Простыми словами - это текстовое поле, которое по цвету совпадает с цветом окна формы и на нем написан информационный текст. Необходимо нарисовать линию по  нижней границе Textbox, над которой и будет этот информационный текст.
Я пробовал рисовать сразу с помощью

```
txt.CreateGraphics().DrawLinе...
```

но ничего не выходит (линия не появляется).

МОжет кто даст дельный совет?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Линия появляется, но сразу же затирается.

Рисовать на поверхности контролов нужно в событии `Paint` - тогда при каждой перерисовке всё будет выводиться заново.

Проблема в том, что у текстбокса это событие не работает.

Судя по словам "информационный текст" - он не будет редактироваться пользователем. Предлагаю взамен TextBox использовать Label, т. к. у него это событие работает.

```
private void SetLabel(int x, int y, string text)
{
    var label = new Label();
    label.Location = new Point(x, y);

    label.Size = new Size(200, 15);
    label.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(176, 178, 183);

    label.Font = new Font("Verdana", 16.5f, FontStyle.Italic);
    label.Text = text;

    Controls.Add(label);
    label.Paint += Label_Paint;
}
```

По умолчанию у ярлыка бордюра нет, поэтому можно не указывать `None`. Цвет его фона по умолчанию равен цвету формы, поэтому тоже можно не указывать.

И обработчик события:

```
private void Label_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var label = (Label)sender;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(57, 54, 56));
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, label.Height - 1, label.Width, label.Height - 1);
}
```

Если всё же `Label` не подходит, т. к. предполагается редактирование текста пользователем, пишите, подумаем.

---

Поступаем так: помещаем на форму панель, а уже в неё текстбокс. Нижнюю границу рисуем на этой панели. Высота панели, соответственно, должна быть чуть больше.

```
private void SetTextBox(int x, int y, string text)
{
    var textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    textBox.Size = new Size(200, 25);
    textBox.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(176, 178, 183);
    textBox.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    textBox.Font = new Font("Verdana", 16.5f, FontStyle.Italic);
    textBox.Text = text;

    var panel = new Panel();
    panel.Location = new Point(x, y);
    panel.Size = new Size(200, 28);

    panel.Controls.Add(textBox);
    Controls.Add(panel);
    panel.Paint += Panel_Paint;
}

private void Panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var panel = (Panel)sender;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(57, 54, 56));
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, panel.Height - 1, panel.Width, panel.Height - 1);
}
```

Вот похожий вопрос: [Border on TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679308/how-to-change-textbox-border-color-and-width-in-winforms)

Comment: Да, Label не подходит, та как все таки буду редактировать поле.

Comment: @РоманТимохов - сделал другой вариант.